# Android parse.com How to fetch pointer type data for specific row

Tags: android, parse-platform

In My Android application i used parse.com for database,

In parse.com i having one table named : "UserInfo"
this table having one column  type pointer that point to "UserImages" table 
like : **"userImages" Pointer {UserImages}**

In "UserImages" table having one column named "profilePicture" that having all pics file.

My question is that , i fetch one row of table "UserInfo" but i don't know how to fetch image of this row because it point to another table.

I fetch another row data successfully , but face problem in fetching this "userImages" , Please help me to how to get this perticular row image from the this table that point to another table.

Thank you.
I need more info then i also provide.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code..
first get parse object (pointer) and then get image.

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> offer = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("className");

    offer.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (e == null) {
                // success
                for (ParseObject parseObject : objects) {
                    ParseObject image = parseObject.getParseObject("UserImages");

                    // this is your pointer class
                    ParseFile pf = (ParseFile) image.get("imagename");
                    Log.e("image ", "URL ----- " + pf.getUrl());
                }

                Log.e("TAG ", "get parse pointer object " + Places.size());
            } else {
                // fail
            }
        }
    });
```